# CentOS 6.5 File system permission?

Tags: centos, filesystems

I am wondering, i have installed CentOS 6.5 Live-DVD in my company PC.

After all the LAMP installation is done, am having a trouble with the File System permission settings.

In the File system directory, all the directories under it is not permissible for me (as root) to create any folder / document / paste.

I already set SELinux to disabled.

Am I missing anything?

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l
total 71320
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       73 Mar 11 18:51 ACL.txt
-rw-------. 1 root root     1058 Mar  6 18:23 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    43295 Mar 11 10:01 index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2409 Apr 14  2011 index.html?url=354858
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    11955 Nov 30 00:56 post-install
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      552 Nov 30 00:57 post-install.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     1363 Mar  7 15:47 scrm.pccws-essa.com.crt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     1704 Mar  7 15:47 scrm.pccws-essa.com.key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 14107104 Feb 18 23:10 skype-4.2.0.11-4.el6.i686.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     1756 Jul  8  2013 SYRKIT-GPG-KEY.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 22305590 Nov 28 07:48 teamviewer_linux.rpm
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    51892 Sep 19 00:09 tuning-primer.sh
```

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/fstab
### /etc/fstab
### Created by anaconda on Thu Mar  6 18:22:08 2014
### Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
### See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info /dev/mapper/vg_softsolvers-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=1fb09c11-64e0-4623-9b3a-15bf4cbc4eb5 /boot            ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_softsolvers-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_softsolvers-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# getfacl /root
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
file: root
owner: root
group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount | grep root
/dev/mapper/vg_softsolvers-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
```

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg_softsolvers-lv_root tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   _CentOS-6.5-x86_
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          f75a76dd-7c91-4575-8777-ec50e8a37353
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

Comment: `user::r-x`:  That indicates that the user lacks `write` permission.  Have you tried turning `write` permission back on, e.g. `chmod +w /root`?  (With write permission enabled that line should look like `user::rwx`.)

Comment: i did try chmod u+w /. but to no avail. and recently i did chmod -R gu+w /. it crashed.

Comment: any chance... its related to ACL? because if it is, i really have no idea on using it. am a really fresh beginner.

Comment: Did you try it on '/root' or just '/'?

Comment: both. but i think it worked on / ? because after i used it my previous attempt crashed it.

Comment: used chmod gu+w. so the getfcl table is updated as below. still couldnt access the File system.